# How to improve the performance of openCV functions?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, simd, avx

I recently implemented the 2D convolution program using AVX2. I want to test my implementation. I compared it with openCV, openMP, and compiler's auto vectorizer of ICC 17, GCC 7.1 and clang 4.0. When looking at generated assembly code it seems compilers use AVX2 instructions but they do not improve the performance efficiently. I used openMP and speedups are around 4x on Core i7 6700HQ. I used CMake to build and install OpenCV on my Fedora. First, I used CMake GUI and checked the AVX part. It seems I wasn't able to install openCV with CMake GUI. I tried CMake command line tutorial in [this page](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) and I successfully installed OpenCV on my laptop. The speedup of openCV is around 3x and I think I might miss some thing that prevent openCV to use AVX2 instruction. All this explaination was for make my question more clear and what I want.

**The question is :**  How can I improve the performance of `filter2D` function?

The openCV code is as follow:

```
##include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#define MAX1 1024
#define Pxsize MAX1
#define Pysize Pxsize

//Kernel size
#define Kxsize 3
#define Kysize Kxsize
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

unsigned short int A[Pxsize][Pysize];
unsigned short int B[Pxsize][Pysize];
unsigned short int K[Kxsize][Kysize];


int main(){
    SINGLECORE // I use it to assign the program to a particular core of the CPU
    //filter arguments
    Point anchor;
    double delta;
    int ddepth;

    //assign data between 0 and 255 to the input matrix
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<Pxsize; i++)
        for (j=0; j<Pysize; j++)
            A[i][j] = (i+j)%255;

    //assign data to the kernel
    //assign data between 0 and 255 to the input matrix
    for (i=0; i<Kxsize; i++)
        for (j=0; j<Kysize; j++)
            K[i][j]=1;

    cv::Mat input = cv::Mat(Pxsize, Pysize, CV_8UC1, A);
    cv::Mat output = cv::Mat(Pxsize, Pysize, CV_8UC1, B);
    cv::Mat kernel = cv::Mat::ones(Kxsize, Kysize, CV_8UC1);

    // Initialize arguments for the filter
    anchor = Point( -1, -1 );
    delta = 0;
    ddepth = -1;



        filter2D( input,   output, ddepth ,  kernel, anchor, delta, 1 );


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try cv::getBuildInformation() and print the result.to find out whether AVX2 is active.

Comment: @Micka, does "Built as dynamic libs?:      YES" mean it depends on compiler commands?

Comment: C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc

Comment: C flags (Release):           -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wl,--as-needed   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option

Comment: -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -mno-sse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG